# Wrong result after a division

Tags: c, division

In an exercice I have to give to a function an array and his size to get the average of his value.
So I've tried this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double average(double array[], double array_size);


int main()
{
    double array[4] = {12.0, 20.0, 8.9, 14.7};

    printf("The average of the array is : %lf\n", average(array, 4.0));

    return 0;
}

double average(double array[], double array_size)
{
    int array_average = 0, i = 0;

    while(i < array_size)
    {
        array_average += array[i];
        i++;
    }

    return array_average / array_size;
}
```

I clang the file and run the ./a.out and that return me 13.500000 instead of 13.9 when I do the average with the calculator.

I don't see where is the errors, thanks for your help !

Comment: Why is your `array_size` a double? Why is your `array_average` an int?

Comment: `(int)12.0 + (int)20.0 + (int)8.9 + (int)14.7` is the same as `12 + 20 + 8 + 14` is the same as `54` ... and `54/4.0` is `13.5`

Comment: And don't forget to make `array_size` an `int`.

Comment: In English, arrays have no gender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that can help someone later I post my final code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double average(double array[], double array_size);


int main()
{
    double array[4] = {12.0, 20.0, 8.9, 14.7};

    printf("The average of the array is : %lf\n", average(array, 4.0));

    return 0;
}

double average(double array[], double array_size)
{
    double array_average = 0.0;
    int i = 0;

    while(i < array_size)
    {
        array_average += array[i];
        i++;
    }

    return array_average / array_size;
}
```

Comment: you still didn't make array_size an integer